# Automapper not mapping all child entities within child collection

Tags: c#, automapper

I am having a problem trying to get my entities mapped using Automapper.

I already have the following mappings where 'GearLevel' has a collection of 'Gear' and there will always be 6.

When i map the entities, if the 'Gear' has multiple entities with the same name it only maps one of them so i will only get one of those entities mapped.

Should i be doing something else in my mappings to overcome this and if so how do i configure it?

```
    CreateMap<HeroViewModel, Hero>();
    CreateMap<TagViewModel, Tag>();
    CreateMap<AbilityViewModel, Ability>();
    CreateMap<StatViewModel, Stat>();
    CreateMap<GearLevelViewModel, GearLevel>();
    CreateMap<GearViewModel, Gear>();

    CreateMap<HeroViewModel, RegisterNewHeroCommand>()
        .ConstructUsing(c => new RegisterNewHeroCommand(c.Name, c.Damage))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Tags, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Tags))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Abilities, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Abilities))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Stats, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Stats))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.GearLevels, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GearLevels));
```

I am calling the AutoMapper in the following code and when it calls the mapper the 'viewModel' has all the 'Gear' in the 'GearLevel' but when the 'registerCommand' returns it is missing multiple 'Gear' in the 'GearLevel' with the same name.

```
public async Task Register(HeroViewModel viewModel)
{
    try
    {
         var registerCommand = _mapper.Map<RegisterNewHeroCommand>(viewModel);
         await _mediator.SendCommand(registerCommand);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        _logger.LogError(exception, $"Failed to register '{viewModel.Name}'");
    }
}
```

This uses the following entities:

```
public class HeroViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Damage { get; set; }
    public List<TagViewModel> Tags { get; set; }
    public List<AbilityViewModel> Abilities { get; set; }
    public List<StatViewModel> Stats { get; set; }
    public List<GearLevelViewModel> GearLevels { get; set; }
}

public class GearLevelViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int? Level { get; set; }
    public List<GearViewModel> Gear { get; set; }
}

public class GearViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And the following commands:

```
public class RegisterNewHeroCommand : HeroCommand
{
    public RegisterNewHeroCommand(string name, int? damage)
    {
        Name = name;
        Damage = damage;
    }
}

public abstract class HeroCommand : Command
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
    public int? Damage { get; protected set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; protected set; }
    public List<Ability> Abilities { get; protected set; }
    public List<Stat> Stats { get; protected set; }
    public List<GearLevel> GearLevels { get; protected set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some (minimal) example code showing how it fails?

Comment: The actual code is working and i am getting the 'GearLevel' collection fully mapped, but the child collection of 'Gear' is not.

What code do you need and i can post it?

Comment: Ideally a minimal reproducible example of the problem - so the simplest object model which exhibits the problem with some sample data. You should be able to fit that into your question.

Comment: I have added some more detail in the original question

Comment: I'd suggest you should simply remove all the `MapFrom` calls. It should work theoretically because the names are the same. If that helps I'll put that as the answer

Comment: Andrey, that doesn't seem to have resolved the issue

Comment: although i am getting the same result